# postgresql split select by 12 hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL

```
 SELECT py.id, 
           py.external_id, sv.provider_id,
           gr.path::text||'/'||ag.full_name::text,  
           st.name, sv.name, py.destination, py.amount,
           REPLACE(py.status_id, 'SUCCESS', 'Success'), 
           py.amount_status_id, 
           py.created_dt,
           py.provider_msg
      FROM payment AS py
INNER JOIN services AS sv ON sv.id = py.service_id
INNER JOIN source_types AS st ON st.id = py.source_type_id
INNER JOIN agents AS ag ON ag.id = py.agent_id
INNER JOIN groups AS gr ON gr.id = ag.group_id
     WHERE py.created_dt >= '2021-10-24' AND py.created_dt < '2021-10-25'
```

I have a request like this. How do I split it into 12 hours? So that I have the data for a certain date from 00.00 to 12.00 and from 12.00 to 00.00
For example, for October 24 from 00.00 to 12.00 and for October 24 from 12.00 to 00.00?

Ultimately, this request, I would like to get a result like this:
+-----+-------------+---------------------+
| id  | external_id |     created_dt      |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+
| 111 |         333 | 2021-10-24 00:00:01 |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+

For example from 00.00 to 12.00

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I guess you want split the data of one day into half a day.

You can use function `date_part` to extract hour of the timestamp, and then put it after `where` clause to split data. such as:

```
SELECT py.id, 
           py.external_id, sv.provider_id,
           gr.path::text||'/'||ag.full_name::text,  
           st.name, sv.name, py.destination, py.amount,
           REPLACE(py.status_id, 'SUCCESS', 'Success'), 
           py.amount_status_id, 
           py.created_dt,
           py.provider_msg
      FROM payment AS py
INNER JOIN services AS sv ON sv.id = py.service_id
INNER JOIN source_types AS st ON st.id = py.source_type_id
INNER JOIN agents AS ag ON ag.id = py.agent_id
INNER JOIN groups AS gr ON gr.id = ag.group_id
     WHERE py.created_dt >= '2021-10-24' AND py.created_dt < '2021-10-25'
       AND date_part('hour', py.created_dt) < 12
```

Comment: I tried to do as you advised. Can't figure out how to apply this to my request

Comment: To be sure. For example, I would like to receive SELECT data for October 24, for the time - from 00.00 to 12.00

Comment: Oh, I see you should add the phrase after "where" , `date_part('hour', created_dt) < 12`. I would re-edit my answer